# PHP - parsing txt file

Tags: php, arrays, file, parsing, text-files

i'd like to parse this file:

```
Case    Given       Predicted
No      Class       Class
1       ?               0               [0.80]
2       ?               0               [0.80]
3       ?               0               [0.80]
4       ?               1               [0.75]
5       ?               0               [0.80]
6       ?               0               [0.80]
7       ?               1               [0.75]
8       ?               0               [0.80]
9       ?               0               [0.80]
10      ?               0               [0.80]
11      ?               1               [0.75]
12      ?               0               [0.80]
13      ?               0               [0.80]
14      ?               0               [0.80]
15      ?               0               [0.80]
16      ?               0               [0.80]
17      ?               0               [0.80]
18      ?               0               [0.80]
19      ?               0               [0.80]
20      ?               0               [0.80]
```

Especially, i want to take values from third column ("Predicted class").I open file thanks to:

```
$txt_file    = file_get_contents('simone.result');
$array        = explode("\n", $txt_file);
array_shift($array);
array_shift($array);
array_shift($array);
```

And I have this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 ? 0 [0.80] [1] => 2 ? 0 [0.80]
```

Ok this is correct. But I want only the third value ("0" or "1") in each key of this array. Does anyone can help me please?

Thank you so much!

Comment: what is column separator? a couple of spaces?

Comment: I don't know. It's created automatically. I think is a TAB.

Comment: -1 for "I don't know". it's YOUR program and you SHOULD know your data before asking other people for help.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel I don't understand why -1. The question was "what is column separator? A couple of spaces?" and my answer was that because this file is automatically created as a result of an algorithm. So i don't know if that is a column separator or something else. It is auto-generated. :)

Comment: You are talking nonsense. "auto-generated" in not an excuse. It doesn't matter who generated this file. YOU have got this file to work with. You have it. And you need to know the separator to solve your task. So, you have to investigate it. Nobody can do it but you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$lines = file('simone.result');
$column3 = array();
for( $i = 2, $ilen = count( $lines ); $i < $ilen; $i++ )
{
    $columns = preg_split( '/\s+/', $lines[ $i ] );
    $column3[] = $columns[ 2 ];
}

var_dump( $column3 );
```

Comment: No result from "var_dump($column3)";

Comment: I don't know why. I think you're correct, but in my script it doesn't working, i get always this stupid blank page!

Comment: @Andre: activate displaying of errors: `ini_set( 'display_errors', true );` and set error level high: `error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );`. Put those two lines at the top of your script (only on a development machine) and tell us if error messages appear on your screen.

Comment: OK... there was some bad code under the script. SOrry for loosing time Man. Thanks a Lot. I really appreciate that!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simply explode your string by a space and use the value you want?

Comment: I tried that. But it seems not working. 
$array2 = explode(" "; $array);
print_r ($array2);
If i print $array2 i get blank page.

Comment: why did you put a semicolon between the arguments? no wonder you get a blank page with that ^^

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
foreach( $array as $key => $value ) {
    $split = explode( " ", $value );
    $array[$key] = $split[2]; 
}
```

Comment: What gives a blank page? A var_dump( $array )?

Answer (score -1):

retrieve all the lines of the file

```
$lines = file($txt_file);
```

then loop on them:

```
foreach($lines as $line ) 
{
    list($v1,$v2,$v3,$v4) = explode("\n", trim($line)); //assuming separator is a space \t for tab

    //take the values you need here
    $tmp[] = $v3;

}

print_r($tmp);
```

as well this work if the file is well written :)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel added a comment

Comment: @Andre: this was just an example to better re-write your code (avoiding 3 array_shifts), I'm kinda sure it works fine. All depends how your file is written. IF separator is a tab (\t), space(\n), or what else..

Comment: i'd like to know why i've got a -1, since this is a fine solution to the problem..